# Is there a way to make DbSet.AddOrUpdate case sensitive?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbset

I have a data set (show below) where each record is unique on two fields when **considering case senstivity** -

```
var dataSet1 = new DataSet() { Country = "UK", City = "London", ... }
var dataSet1 = new DataSet() { Country = "UK", City = "LONDON", ... }
```

On executing `DBSet.AddOrUpdate`() as below -

```
database.DataSets.AddOrUpdate(ds => new
{
    ds.Country,
    ds.City,
}, dataList.ToArray());

database.SaveChanges();
```

I am getting `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element`

The cause of this exception is pretty obvious as it will return two records when querying for `City = 'London'`

**Question** - Is there a way to make DbSet.AddOrUpdate case sensitive?

**PS:** The dataset is coming from external source so I cannot tweak it to persist. For instance, change City to UPPER CASE and ignore duplicates is not allowed.

Comment: What is the collation of your database?

Comment: Aah! Collation of my Database is 'Latin1_General_CI_AS'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your database to Case Sensitive. At the moment it's CI (Case Insensitive).